# "Update can not be used in this context"

Tags: file-io, clojure, hashmap

I am new to clojure and I am working on a problem...

I'm am trying to find the frequency of all the instructors I have in a file, but I have no idea where to start. I did this before in a different program and it worked, but now i am getting an error that reads "Update can not be used in this context"

```
(defn read-lines [filename]
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
    (doall (line-seq rdr))))

(defn classes [s]
  (reduce conj (map hash-map [:semester :title :crn :code :levels :credits 
:campus :section :capacity :actual :starthout :startmin
                          :endhour :endmin :weekday :room :datestart 
:dateend :schtypye :instructor :prereq :corereq] (.split s ";"))))

(println(map classes (read-lines "C:/Users/Rohil's Computer/Desktop/textfile.txt")))

(loop [semester->instructor {}
   [{:keys [semester instructor] :as row} & rows] classes]
(if (nil? row)
semester->instructor
(recur (update semester->instructor semester (fnil conj []) instructor) rows)))
```

Comment: You first define `classes` as a function, then (in the loop form) you seem to be using it as a sequence.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do too much at one time here, in between runs of the code.  You will be happier if you add only a little bit at a time, and print out the results after adding each bit. Then you can see where things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you really didn't ask a specific question I'm going to extrapolate given what you said and the code that you posted.

The real question is "Where do I start?"

In Clojure that answer is always "at the repl"

so first you defined `read-lines`, which seems to take a file name and returns a collection with each item in the collection being the line of the file passed in

That's simple enough and easy to test at the repl.

but then you have the `classes` function which seems to take a semi-colon delimited string and tries to split it at the semi colon to make a map of the hard-coded keys to values in the string.

After that it kind of goes off the rails.

So lets pick up before that and look at a simpler example; follow along at the repl

```
(defn classes [s]
   (reduce conj (map hash-map [:instructor :semester] 
                (.split s ";"))))
```

`(map classes ["bob;1" "jack;2" "bob;3"])` returns a collection of maps. in this case it returns `({:semester "1", :instructor "bob"}
 {:semester "2", :instructor "jack"}
 {:semester "3", :instructor "bob"})`

we want to get the frequencies of all names so lets pull those out into a simple list by mapping the instructor keyword over this collection of maps like so:

`(map :instructor (map classes ["bob;1" "jack;2" "bob;3"]))` so we get 
`("bob" "jack" "bob")`

now we can just call `frequencies` on that collection to get a map of name to frequency like this:
`(frequencies (map :instructor (map classes ["bob;1" "jack;2" "bob;3"])))`

this returns `{"jack" 1, "bob" 2}`

Now that each of those individual pieces seems to be working at the repl we can put them all together:

```
(->> (read-lines "C:/Users/Rohil's Computer/Desktop/textfile.txt")
     (map classes)
     (map :instructor)
     frequencies)
```